# what to do if end user has no flash plugin for firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, mp3

I am testing MediaElements audio mp3 file player for Firefox with no Flash plugin installed. What happens now is the download option appears and also adds an extra line to the player moving the rest of the content out of balance.
What do I need to change in the code to make mp3 file play in Firefox without a Flash plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some flavor of HTML5 audio.  IF you've got a mobile version of the site, you probably can reuse the html5 you wrote to provide audio there.  If not, your site will be broken in a lot more locations than just FF-without flash.